# Automapper ConstructServicesUsing in Umbraco 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper, umbraco

I recently have been working on a small side project using Umbraco 8, and I set myself a challenge of getting Auto-mapper working with the Dependency Injection.
I've got basic mappers working however getting the DI to inject in to the mappers using the 'ConstructServicesUsing'  has been more tricky.

To get it to work I have had to bind my TypeConverter classes directly when I'm binding the mapper.

Have I overlooked something key? or is there a way for me select all ITypeConverter in the assembly and bind them automatically?

```
 public class MapperConfigurationComposer : IComposer
    {
        public void Compose(Composition composition)
        {
            var serviceContainer = composition.Concrete as LightInject.ServiceContainer;


            var mapperConfiguration = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {               
                cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());

                cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(type => serviceContainer.TryGetInstance(type));
            });

            var mapper  = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();

            composition.Register(mapper);

            composition.Register<SearchResultToSearchResultResponseItemTypeConverter>();

        }


    }
```

```
  internal class MappingProfile: AutoMapper.Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {

            CreateMap<ISearchResult, SearchResultResponseItem>().ConvertUsing<SearchResultToSearchResultResponseItemTypeConverter>();
        }

    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L59

Comment: UmbracoMapper may be an option? https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Reference/Mapping/?_ga=2.98174495.1403028710.1562569887-381923933.1557318288/